# question about skype

Tags: skype

After a successfull installation of ubuntu 16.04 alongside with windows 10 I have installed skype using the version from skype site which is a beta version. As I don't like it I want to install another version that I have on my dropbox (version  5.0 ....). I removed beta version  using ubuntu software and when I installed the 5.0 what comes out is always same beta version that I have installed before. I think this happens because not all files of the beta version were removed. How can I remove completely all traces of the beta version ?

Comment: After removing the beta go to terminal and type: sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: Sorry Muaad that didn't wotk.When I install again I get same beta version.!!!

Comment: I think the problem is that every command I enter to remove (remove , purge , etc...) I get always same message: not possible to find the skype package !!!

Answer (score 1):

All versions of skype for ubuntu are called "beta" so your version 5.0 is beta, too!

[skype blog announcement](https://blogs.skype.com/news/2017/03/01/the-skype-for-linux-beta-version-5-0-is-now-available-for-download/)

Comment: I didn't know that, but anyway this last version misses a lot of configurations and that's why I don't like.The one I mentioned 5.0.xxx was really better.Can someone please tell me how to get ride of this version ??

Comment: Ok if no solution I will keep this version for some more time.

Comment: @HilarioFerreira if it fixes your issue you should mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you manage to downgrade Skype successfully, you should be aware that Microsoft/Skype management can, from the server side, disable "legacy" client versions whenever they decide that too many changes have been made to continue to support the older versions.  When they do this, the client will still open, but you won't be able to make or receive a call.

This has historically not been a common problem on the Linux side, because Microsoft makes few updates/changes to the Linux client, but I'd recommend using the newest version available to avoid being caught with this at a moment when the time to find and install an up to date version of Skype isn't available.